# How to introduce a widow who is not a widow?

Tags: word-request, american-english

I am looking for a way to introduce a mother, who believes she is a widow in a logline in a way that the reader understands that she is not a widow.
The long version would be:
"A widow, who is unaware that her husband still lives in desperation to secure her children’s future falls for an upper-class predator, who treats people like Nazis did the Jews."
How could I shorten the “who is unaware that her husband still lives?”

Answer (score 3):

> *A woman, believing herself widowed*...

That's one good one.